# How can I reboot my phone without the power or volume buttons?

Tags: reboot, buttons, power-on

Title is pretty self-explanatory. My phone's power and volume buttons don't work. The home button does. It's a Lenovo ZUK Z2 Plus.

This phone has always had a tendency to crash unless rebooted occasionally. Now that the power button doesn't work, I won't be able to turn the phone on if it crashes and shuts down.

I've taken a complete backup, but I'd still like to continue using the phone for as long as possible. In order to prevent the inevitable crash, I'd like to reboot the phone every so often. How can I do so?

Comment: Can you not get the buttons repaired?

Comment: @Burgi No, spare parts aren't available anywhere in this city. Believe me, I've looked.

Comment: Do you have root access? It would be very easy than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Scheduled Power On/Off features available in the Accessibility setting to turn it off, then back on a minute or two later.

Comment: This! Also allows me to switch my phone on automatically in case it shuts down.